# mvc razor not paging through information

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I am trying to page through some information, however the data is not changing when I click any of the other pages.

Controller:

```
 public ActionResult Student(string currentFilter, string searchString, int? page)
    {
        if (searchString != null)
        {
            page = 1;
        }
        ViewBag.CurrentFilter = currentFilter;
        ViewBag.SearchString = searchString;

        var students = new List<Student>();

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(searchString))
        {
            var studentStore = new StudentStore();
            students = studentStore.ReadFiltered(currentFilter, searchString);
            page = 1;
        }

        int pageSize = 15;
        int pageNumber = (page ?? 1);

        return View(students.ToPagedList(pageNumber, pageSize));

    }
```

View:

```
@using Directory.Models
@model PagedList.IPagedList<Student>
@using PagedList.Mvc;

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Student";
    Layout = null;
 }

<h2>Student</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm("Student", "Web", FormMethod.Get))
{
   @Html.TextBox("CurrentFilter", ViewBag.CurrentFilter as string)

   <p>
     Find by name: @Html.TextBox("SearchString", ViewBag.CurrentFilter as 
                   string)
        <input type="submit" value="Search" />
   </p>
    }

<table>

    @foreach (var item in Model)
{

    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.LastName)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.FirstName)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Email)
        </td>
    </tr>

}

</table>
<br/>

        Page @(Model.PageCount < Model.PageNumber ? 0 : Model.PageNumber) of @Model.PageCount

@Html.PagedListPager( Model, page => Url.Action("Student", new { page,currentFilter = ViewBag.CurrentFilter, searchString = ViewBag.SearchString }))
```

I am getting the full list of students however when I try to limit the results to 15 per page I am only getting the first 15 and when I click to another page the information displayed is not changing.

Comment: Try putting a break point in on the action method and see what is the parameter values are and step through. My guess is that `searchString` may be `string.empty` rather than null and therefore you are forcing it to 1 every time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just ended up removing all the page = 1 lines and it is able to cycle through the information.